# FastAPI AttributeError: 'Depends' object has no attribute 'query'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I'm trying to access my database with fast API. I'm having some problems getting access to it if done it outside of an endpoint.

I'm trying to access the DB and retrieve the allowed emails. I can do that in the get/post (/refresh) endpoints, but not in the route (/token), it throws the error: ''Depends' object has no attribute 'query''

From what I understand the depends can only be solved in an API route, so I tried to create a new post endpoint and call it from the route. The result is that the request gets stuck...

```
@router.route('/login')
async def login(request: Request):
    #REQUEST GET STUCK IN PENDING
    await requests.post(url="http://localhost:8000/auth" + '/set-users')
    
    redirect_uri = FRONTEND_URL  # This creates the url for our /auth endpoint
    return await oauth.google.authorize_redirect(request, redirect_uri)

@router.post('/set-users')
def set_useres(database: Session = Depends(db_handler.get_db)):
    emails = brand_operation_handler.get_all_users(db=database)
    print(emails)
    allowed_email_in_user_table_setter(emails)
    return ''

@router.route('/token')
async def auth(request: Request, database: Session = Depends(db_handler.get_db)): #,  database: Session = Depends(db_handler.get_db)
    try:
        access_token = await oauth.google.authorize_access_token(request)
    except OAuthError:
        raise CREDENTIALS_EXCEPTION
    user_data = await oauth.google.parse_id_token(request, access_token)

    
    #emails = brand_operation_handler.get_all_users(db=database)
    # allowed_email_in_user_table_setter(emails)



    if (valid_email_from_db(user_data['email'])): #or valid_email_from_user_table(user_data['email'])
        return JSONResponse({
            'result': True,
            'access_token': create_token(user_data['email']),
            'refresh_token': create_refresh_token(user_data['email']),
            'user_data': user_data
        })
    raise CREDENTIALS_EXCEPTION


@router.post('/refresh')
async def refresh(request: Request, database: Session = Depends(db_handler.get_db)):
    
    #THIS WORKS
    emails = brand_operation_handler.get_all_users(db=database)
    print(emails)
    allowed_email_in_user_table_setter(emails)

    try:
        # Only accept post requests
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = await request.json()
            if form.get('grant_type') == 'refresh_token':
                token = form.get('refresh_token')
                payload = decode_token(token)
                # Check if token is not expired
                if datetime.utcfromtimestamp(payload.get('exp')) > datetime.utcnow():
                    email = payload.get('sub')
                    # Validate email
                    # database: Session = Depends(db_handler.get_db)
                    # get_user_table(database)
                    if valid_email_from_db(email): #or valid_email_from_user_table(email)
                        # Create and return token
                        return JSONResponse({'result': True, 'access_token': create_token(email)})

    except Exception:
        raise CREDENTIALS_EXCEPTION
    raise CREDENTIALS_EXCEPTION
```

Comment: Post the stacktrace

Comment: How are you calling the `route` definitions? If you want to call them directly, why define them as routes? If you want to call it directly, call the function itself (`get_db`) with the necessary parameters instead of relying on the dependency framework to resolve the parameters for you.

Comment: @MatsLindh the get_db can only be resolved inside an endpoint otherwise I would have just call it in another function.

Comment: Which is what you're expected to do if you're not in a web request context (i.e. in a cli script or a console application); just call `get_db` yourself instead of using `Depends`; they're just normal functions, so call them with the arguments necessary. I'm also not sure why you're using `router.route` directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason `Depends` is not working is, as @MatsLindh is asking about, that you are calling `router.route` directly. That is the underlying method in Starlette, meaning you bypass all FastAPI specific functionality, *like `Depends`*. Rewrite it using `router.get` and it should work.